# React Native - How to remove 1px navigation bar hairline from NavigationExperimental's NavigationHeader?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

In React Native, is it possible to remove the navigation bar's 1px hairline from `NavigationExperimental`'s `NavigationHeader`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in a style prop to NavigationHeader. From the code https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationHeader.js it looks like you would need something like

```
<NavigationHeader style={{borderBottomWidth: 0}} ...etc etc/>
```

Untested :)